# Computed attributes in python class

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python.
I have a class in python that has a constructor. I would like to create some attributes within the constructor itself.
I tried all the obvious ways but no use, please help:

```
class X:
      def __init__ (self, A):
           self.A = A
           my_dict = {}
           my_dict[A] = 1

object_X.my_dict ##Need a way to access the parameter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
self.my_dict = {}
```

to make `my_dict` an attribute of `self`.

This and much more is explained in the section on [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) in the Python tutorial.